# how to redirect domain.com/images/image.jpg to domain2.com/images/image.jpg

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to redirect `domain.com/images/image.jpg` to `domain2.com/images/image.jpg`?

Right now, `domain.com/images/image.jpg` is redirecting to `domain2.com` without carrying to the image folder and subsequent image.jpg.  Can this be accomplished in .htaccess?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I've edited your question to make it more clear what is happening and what you would like to accomplish.  Can you please let us know how you currently are redirecting this (if in .htaccess, what do you have written)?

Comment: I'm not sure it  this is what you want, but here it is... RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is the above in addition to my current rule or should it replace my existing rule?  Thanks

Comment: This should replace your existing rule.

Comment: This should be first rule just below `RewriteEngine` line. Also make sure this htaccess is being read by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: I did not get a 500 error after putting nonsensical text at the top of the .htaccess  Does this mean that this .htaccess is not the one being used by the server?  I only have one .htaccess on my server.  The other .htaccess has numbers after it... For example, .htaccess_12345678 (different numbers, of course)

Comment: Yes this means htaccess is not enabled. You should talk to your hosting admins for enabling it.